# indirect ssh, connection closed after a single command

Tags: ssh

I was trying to execute multiple commands through multiple ssh, basically:

**ssh -t host1 ssh -t host2 ssh -t host3 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'**

I want to execute all the commands on the end host (host3). But what happens if I use the above line is that the connection to host3 and to host2 closed immediately after "cmd1;"

As an example, if I use hostname for cmd1, cmd2 and cmd3, the out put will be

**host3 

Connection to host3 closed.

Connection to host2 closed.

host1

host1

Connection to host1 closed.**

If I use double quotes in the following way

**ssh -t host1 "ssh -t host2 ssh -t host3 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'"**
or 
**ssh -t host1 ssh -t host2 "ssh -t host3 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'"**

I get the output:

**host3

Connection to host3 closed.

host2

host2

Connection to host2 closed.

Connection to host1 closed.**

Could somebody explain this to me? and how can I get all commands executed on host3

Answer (score 4):

All it takes is lots of quotations:

```
ssh -t host1 'ssh -t host2 "ssh -t host3 '"'"'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'"'"'"'
```

What I did here was just to take your last command and add `'` around it. However something else needs to be adjusted accordingly. Any previously existing `'` inside the part, which I put `'` around would need to be replaced with `'"'"'`

The reason replacing `'` with `'"'"'` works is this:

- The first `'` terminates the quoted string.
- The first `"` starts a new string quoted with `"`
- The middle `'` is not interpreted by the shell, it is just treated as a literal.
- The last `"` ends the string quoted by `"`
- The last `'` starts a new quoted string.
- The three strings are automatically concatenated by the shell.